# Google Drive API communication protocol

Tags: google-drive-api

We are writing a program to post spreadsheets in google drive using Drive API. Please see below code sample that creates an instance of Drive.Builder.  Our IT security team would like to know if the communication protocol for posting files to drive using this method would be HTTPS (SSL/TLS). Can you please confirm?

---

```
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

try {
httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}


InputStream credentialsJSON = GoogleDrive.class.getResourceAsStream("Path to Json File of the Service Account");
GoogleCredential gcFromJson = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsJSON, httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY)
.createScoped(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(gcFromJson.getTransport())
.setJsonFactory(gcFromJson.getJsonFactory())
.setServiceAccountId(gcFromJson.getServiceAccountId())
.setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
.setServiceAccountPrivateKey(gcFromJson.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
.setServiceAccountScopes(gcFromJson.getServiceAccountScopes())
.build(); 

// set up the global Drive instance
return new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, Utilities.setHttpTimeout(credential)).setApplicationName(
APPLICATION_NAME).build();

}
```

Comment: what about official api support lines? I had some questions when I integrate some other google service and usually they give good and clear answer for question.

Comment: This is what I received from GCP support. Hence I posted this question here. --- "Unfortunately, Drive API isn't supported by Google Cloud Platform so I'll be unable help with this case as it's out of scope for support. However, you may find this link [1] useful on Drive API reference.

As mentioned here [2], you can post your question/any future Drive API-related questions on Stack Overflow. The direct link to Stack Overflow with the google-drive-sdk tag can be found here [3]." ---

Comment: All Google services use TLS

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks for the confirmation.